# Nested select with clause with AS operator

Tags: sql

I'm learning `nested select` and I've encountered a problem with `AS` operator within the second (i.e. nested `select`).

Please have a look at the following table (truncated):

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+--------------+
|    name     | continent |  area   | population |     gdp      |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+--------------+
| Afghanistan | Asia      |  652230 |   25500100 |  20343000000 |
| Albania     | Europe    |   28748 |    2831741 |  12960000000 |
| Algeria     | Africa    | 2381741 |   37100000 | 188681000000 |
| Andorra     | Europe    |     468 |      78115 |   3712000000 |
| Angola      | Africa    | 1246700 |   20609294 | 100990000000 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+--------------+
```

**The aim is to show the countries in Europe with a per capita GDP greater than that of United Kingdom's.** (Per capita GDP is the gdp/population).

The following query is correct in terms of syntax but it will not give the correct result as it selects `gdp` instead of `gdp/population`:

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE gdp/population >
    (SELECT gdp
     FROM world
     WHERE name = 'United Kingdom')
  AND continent = 'Europe';
```

One solution to correct this would be using `gdp/population` instead of `gdp` in `nested select` but the resulting query would be incorrect in terms of syntax. Why? I use MariaDB but I'd like the query to be not dependent on DBMS provider.

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE gdp/population >
    (SELECT gdp AS gdp/population
     FROM world
     WHERE name = 'United Kingdom')
  AND continent = 'Europe';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AS` syntax is

```
SELECT expression AS ALIAS
```

So you got it the wrong way round, and the alias you are defining contains an illegal character (`/`). An alias is not required in this case, so you can simply do:

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE gdp/population >
    (SELECT  gdp/population
     FROM world
     WHERE name = 'United Kingdom')
  AND continent = 'Europe';
```